# Preprocessor settings confusion

Tags: ios, preprocessor-directive

I am trying to do a simple test when I am in DEV mode or when I am in RELEASE mode using the preprocessor settings. My settings are as follows:

[image: preprocessor settings]

I also have a constant.h file that I include in the App-prefix.pch file.

The contents of the file are as follows:

```
#ifndef myapp_Constants_h
#define myapp_Constants_h




    #pragma mark - Instances
    #ifdef DEBUG
    #define WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL @"http://local.someurl.com/"
    #define LOGIN_PATH @"app_dev.php/user/login/"
    #define REGISTER_PATH @"app_dev.php/user/register/"
    #endif


    #ifdef RELEASE
    #define WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL @"http://www.someurl.com/"
    #define LOGIN_PATH @"user/login/"
    #define REGISTER_PATH @"user/register/"
    #endif

#endif
```

When I run the app on my iphone plugged to the mac, I always seem to get the DEBUG mode settings even though I should get the RELEASE settings.

why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode's default configuration is to run in Debug, even on device. If you want to run your app in release, you can :

- Use "Profile" (Command-I) or "Archive" (and then install the resulting app).
- Modify your scheme by choosing "Product -> Edit Scheme". (Or using Command-Option-R.) Click on the "Run" scheme, and change the "Build Configuration" to "Release". (It's in the "Info" panel.)

If you want to switch back and forth frequently, you could make another scheme (in "Manage Schemes") and modify it to use the release build configuration. You can then easily switch between them with the scheme selector in the top-left corner of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that DEBUG is always defined when you run attached to Xcode.

One solution would be

```
#ifdef RELEASE
    // release constants

#else
    // debug constants

#endif
```

This way, your RELEASE define would override the DEBUG.

Edit: and in any case where both DEBUG and RELEASE aren't set, you'd still have a viable environment. It might occur.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested and I still get the same outcome.

Comment: If you keep hitting cmd-R to run your project from Xcode, you'll always run in `DEBUG` mode. IIRC you can’t run in definitive release mode until signed with a distribution certificate. What you can do nonetheless, is define the `RELEASE` directive when in `DEBUG` mode, or create a new running scheme that defines the `RELEASE` directive.

Comment: DEBUG is not always defined when you run attached to Xcode, and you only need a distribution certificate to run in release if you've specified such in your code signing settings.